# How can I get a continous geolication from Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, geolocation, location

I'm trying to get the Location of my device continuously using the Xamarin Essentials, but his behavior is quite strange. The GPS signal is activated and disable each time I'm using the GetLocationAsync method (is like a blinking mode).

This is my code:

Main Thread:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(gpsFrequencyRead, () =>
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                if (!isBusy)
                {
                    isBusy = true;
                    await MainMethodProcess();
                    isBusy = false;
                }
            });

            return activeMainTimer;

        });
```

MainMethodProcess:

```
...

Location location = new Location();

location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);

...
```

If I compare this behavior with another app that use GPS location the just activate the GPS signal once and no more. What I doing wrong?

These are the results:

[image: Searching GPS]

[image: Active module]

Comment: You are using Xamarin.Essentials right? i don't think essentials has a listener for location changes, but CrossGeolocator has! i will post an anwser with some code + sources for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, **[Xamarin.Essentials](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/)** doesn't have a location listener to detect location changes in the background.
A solution would be using the the **[Geolocator Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin)** from jamesmontemagno.

Here is an example on how to use it ([source](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92680/how-to-always-get-location-in-background-task-with-xamarin-forms))

```
async Task StartListening()
{
    await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 10, true, new Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ListenerSettings
    {
        ActivityType = 
        Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation,
        AllowBackgroundUpdates = true,
        DeferLocationUpdates = true,
        DeferralDistanceMeters = 1,
        DeferralTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        ListenForSignificantChanges = true,
        PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    });
    CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += Current_PositionChanged;
}

private void Current_PositionChanged(object sender, Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.PositionEventArgs e)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        var Position = e.Position;
    });
}
```